# Barcoding - automatically fetch value if input is not empty

Tags: jquery

Hey I have looked for such questions regarding this stuff but cannot find something useful, I want to make a code which automatically fetches the data if it detects that the input field was filled.

For example I am focused in one input field only then I hit the barcode scanner, So the input was filled something like 71-4112-6568, So the thing is I want to fetch that data automatically then store it in a variable.

I have tried something like this...

```
<input name="barcode" type="text" class="barcode">
```

then

```
$('.barcode').keypress(function(){
    var value = $(this).val();
});
```

Using keypress was just a test. It has a response but definitely not what I am looking for. May someone help me to correct this code accurately. I am going to pass this variable to ajax after this method. Thanks,

Comment: *"Using keypress was just a test. It has a response but definitely not what I am looking for."* - Why not? What are you looking for?

Comment: @billyonecan Hi there, using console.log the value starts from 7 then 71 up to 71-4112-6568 where he finishes the whole value, keypress detects it starting from the first input "7"



and if i make an alert(), it only says "7"

Comment: Are the barcodes a fixed length? If they are, you could just check `this.value.length`, and if it matches, store the value/post the request

Comment: You can use `change` or `blur` if you need the full value.

Answer (score 0):

If your barcodes have a fixed length, you could test that in your `keypress` handler, and only proceed if it meets the requirements, eg:

```
$('.barcode').on('keypress', function() {

  if (!$.trim(this.value).length == 12) {
    return; 
  }

  console.log(this.value);

});
```

Another option would be to set a timeout, and clear it each time `keypress` fires:

```
var timer = 0;
$('.barcode').on('keypress', function() {

    var _this = this;
    clearTimeout(timer);

    timer = setTimeout(function() {
        console.log( _this.value );
    }, 500);

});
```

I'd imagine your barcode scanner inputs quickly, in which case you could drop the delay in `setTimeout()`.

#### [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/L3Dcx/3/)